# Spring Mongo Reactive - OnErrorResume is not working

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working with spring-webflux & reactive MongoDB. As part of error handling (specially from MongoDB side like timeout or connection issues), I have put a default onErrorResume which is not getting triggered. Following is the sample code to reproduce the error -

**Mongo Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface SourceRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Source, String> {
   Mono<Source> findBySource(String source);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class SourceService {
     private final SourceRepository sourceRepository;
     public SourceService(SourceRepository sourceRepository) {
       this.sourceRepository=sourceRepository
     }

     public Mono<Source> getSourceDetails(String source) {
          return sourceRepository.findBySource(source)
            .onErrorResume(ex -> Source.defaultValues()) //This is not working when any Mongo Error
     }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class SourceController {
   private final SourceService sourceService;
   public SourceController(SourceService sourceService) {
     this.sourceService=sourceService;
   }

   @GetMapping("/api/source/{name}")
   public Mono<Source> getSourceDetails(@PathVariable String name) {
      return sourceService.getSourceDetails(name);
   }
}
```

I have tried onErrorResume on controller method but it is not working there as well. However, if I keep it inside try-catch, then I am able to catch the exception and send default values.

However, I am trying to avoid try-catch and use the standard onErrorResume or onErrorContinue. Any help or idea where it is going wrong.

Comment: What is the exception that is not handled?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi MongoTimeoutException. As and when we are getting this, it is not handled. We tried to simulate the same behavior using JUnit and it is the same behavior.

Comment: the exception in question is observable as an `onError` event? it is not _thrown_ by the repository, correct? ie. you can see it in logs if you put a `.log()` right after `findBySource(source)` in the service? if at that point an exception is thrown that would constitute a bug in spring-data-mongodb or mongo client itself.

Comment: @SimonBaslé I tried putting .log() and I don't see any error being logged/thrown. Does this mean the error is with Mongo Client?

Comment: probably. it means the exception is not propagated in a reactive fashion but appears to be thrown from the repository or underneath it. `onErrorResume` can only deal with exceptions it receives in the form of an `onError` signal, it cannot catch thrown exceptions.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it looks like the `sourceRepository.findBySource(...)` call itself **throws** a timeout exception, which isn't something to be expected from most reactive methods / libraries.

As `onErrorResume` is a reactive operator, it can only react to an incoming `onError` signal, and cannot catch an exception thrown in an imperative fashion.

The problem probably lies in either spring-data-mongodb or the underlying mongodb client.